# Autocommit not happening all the time

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was trying to change the auto commit status and update it later based on a condition. But once in 10 times the data is not getting committed as the auto commit status is getting changed some how. I am not able to find out how.

I have attached my code below.

```
removeEmployee(){
        conn = DbManager.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        stat = conn.createStatement();
        int updated = stat.executeUpdate(updateSql);
        if (updated > 0) {
            boolean credit = isCreditPeding();
            System.out.println("Is Credit:"+credit);
            if(credit){
                System.out.println("Condition"+!conn.getAutoCommit());
                if (!conn.getAutoCommit()) {
                    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                    conn.commit();
                }
                conn.setAutoCommit(true);
                return true;
            }else{
                conn.rollback();
                conn.setAutoCommit(true);
            }
        }
    }

Result (During error)
Is Credit:true
condition:false
```

The connection is not modified in the `isCreditPending()` Method. The record is not committed even if I am calling `setAutocommit(true)`.

Answer (score 1):

> The record is not committed even if I am calling setAutocommit(true).

It will not. You will have to explicitly commit it since you have set autoCommit to false at the beginning of your method.

```
removeEmployee(){
        boolean committed = false;
        conn = DbManager.getConnection();
        boolean initValue = conn.getAutoCommit(); //save the initial value
        conn.getAutoCommit(false); //explicitly set it to false to control the transaction
        stat = conn.createStatement();
        int updated = stat.executeUpdate(updateSql);
        if (updated > 0) {
            boolean credit = isCreditPeding();
            System.out.println("Is Credit:"+credit);
            if(credit){
                con.commit();//explicitly commit
                committed = true;
            }else{
                conn.rollback();//explicitly rollback
            }              
        }              
    }
    con.setAutoCommit(initValue);
    return committed;
```

Comment: I mentioned that because in the java docs of autoComit it says lie this.

**NOTE: If this method is called during a transaction and the auto-commit mode is changed, the transaction is committed. If setAutoCommit is called and the auto-commit mode is not changed, the call is a no-op.**

Comment: You are right. It does say that. And you are seeing erratic behavior. IMHO, it is better to control your transactions with explicit commits and/or rollbacks. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html